# how to create an ASP.NET Web Page to manage folders and files for loading and reading to an external server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, html, shared-directory

I need to create a Web page that manages a shared folder, which means you can upload and download files, these preferably pdf and a certain size. This shared folder has security therefore must be accessed in any way with user key.

I need to know if there is some sort or some method easy to perform in ASP C#, give me options to view folders and their files created and upload new in a new folder.

I would appreciate your help and advice in order to make this website.

Comment: if all you want to do is manage a documents folder, then you could use SharePoint. the basic version is free, and it even has basic version control for your documents.

Comment: it's clearly an Active Server Page :p

Comment: I thought it might be the same thing as "a WCF".

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` and `System.IO.FileInfo` to work with a file system from .NET.

Using 'System.IO.FileStream' in one way to create new files from binary data (stream or byte[])

Answer (score 0):

Easy way would be to use a third party control like [FileUltimate](http://www.gleamtech.com/products/fileultimate/asp-net-file-manager-control)
Or you can bulid your own custom file manager by using utility classes in [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) and [HttpResponse class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) for file streaming